# Loading multiple files of different scheme to BigQuery using DataFlow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a set of .txt file with data in JSON format with varying schema, all of them to be loaded to a common bigquery table. File format is simple, one set of files will have 4 columns, some has 5, some has same 5 but in different order...

Eg: File  inFolder 1 '{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}'

File  in Folder 2 '{"name":"Tom", "age":32, "city":"New York", "zip":"12345"}'

File  in Folder 3 '{"name":"Janice", "age":31, "zip":"12345", "city":"New York"}'

File  in Folder 4 '{"name":"Alice", "age":34, "zip":"12348"}'

File  in Folder 5 '{"name":"Rob", "age":31, "zip":"12345", "Phone":"1234567891"}'

The BQ table will be of columns, name, age, city, zip, phone.

Each types of files are in separate folders in GCS, files in each folder are consistent , with in a GCS bucket subfolder all files are of same type, same number and order of columns.

I am able to load these files individually to corresponding BQ tables, but I need them to a single table by loading NULL for the 'not applicable' column .

seeking advices to load data using data flow to BQ as a batch process. I am pretty new to this,  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch?hl=en_US#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery), a Google-provided template, can be used for your use case.

As described in the documentation, please create the BigQuery schema file that's a union of all known schemas and a JavaScript file to handle any missing fields (BigQuery may be able to automatically replace missing values with nulls, but I haven't tested that).

You can follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates?hl=en_US) to launch a template job.

---

Update: based on the comment, it looks like you're interested in creating your own pipeline. This is how you'd read from GCS and write to BigQuery.

```py
schema="name:STRING,age:INTEGER,zip:STRING,phone:STRING,city:STRING"

_ = (p
    | "read messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://path/to/files/*.txt')
    | "parse" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
    | 'write to bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('project:datasetId.tableId', schema=schema)
)
```

Unspecified values are automatically saved as `null`s.

This is how I saved the data.

```
$ gsutil cat gs://path/to/files/example.txt
{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I need a data flow pipeline (python) due to other complexities in the solution.

Comment: @rens Updated my answer to help you write your own.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is what I did , I was thinking it needs the schema 1:1 matching which is not true. Your advise helped me to try it and it worked well.